# magento 2 block function not calling my phtml

Tags: magento2, xml, custom-block

Magento 2 Block function not calling. How to call

**PHP**

```
<?php

namespace MPS\Allproduct\Block\New\List;


class List extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function myTest(){
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="MPS\Allproduct\Block\New\List" name="allproduct_index_index" template="MPS_Allproduct::allproduct_index_index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your class namespace and the class you have given block.

Your class namespace sould be upto the parent directory where you class resides.

Your name space should be as below if New is parent directory of the class.

```
namespace MPS\Allproduct\Block\BlockNew;
```

Note: New is reserved keyword for PHP try changing the folder name and name space. 
you can take the reference from [This Link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html)

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: MPS\Allproduct\Block\New
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class MPS\Allproduct\Block\New does not exist

Comment: U dont need to change anything in xml just edit the name space

Comment: <block class="MPS\Allproduct\Block\New" name="allproduct_new_list" template="MPS_Allproduct::allproduct_index_index.phtml"/>

Comment: Ur xml class should look like. class="MPS\Allproduct\Block\New\List".. Dont forget to clear the cache if you are not in developer mode

Comment: This page isn’t working unable to handle the request

Comment: try debugging , check if its reaching to your controller.

Comment: Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'New' (T_NEW), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in proj/app/code/MPS/Allproduct/Block/New/List.php on line 3

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: I already tried but no luck can you plz update with sample code and folder structure

Comment: Try the link I have given

Answer (score 0):

Add the **_contructor**:

```
public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->validator = $context->getValidator();
        $this->resolver = $context->getResolver();
        $this->_filesystem = $context->getFilesystem();
        $this->templateEnginePool = $context->getEnginePool();
        $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        $this->_appState = $context->getAppState();
        $this->templateContext = $this;
        $this->pageConfig = $context->getPageConfig();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: MPS\Allproduct\Block\List\List
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class MPS\Allproduct\Block\List\List does not exist

Comment: Change your namespace to namespace MPS\Allproduct\Block\New on the PHP

Answer (score 0):

Keep `namespace MPS\Allproduct\Block\New`; instead of `namespace MPS\Allproduct\Block\New\List;`

Please keep below code in your block file,
You have used **List** two times so issue is there for you,

```
<?php

namespace MPS\Allproduct\Block\New;


class List extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function myTest(){
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you try with above code? Please let me know if you have issue